# Names of deleted users missing from bounty notices

Tags: bug, status-completed, bounty, deleted-users

In light of a recent sockpuppetry case, I discovered [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33340211/464709) whose author started a bounty (which was resolved) before being deleted. The resulting [revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/33340211/revisions) is quite strange:

[image]

As you can see, the name of the deleted user does not appear in the notice reports, resulting in incomplete sentences.

It seems that following user deletion, the Community user has taken ownership of the bounty but not of the notices. For consistency reasons, it probably should take ownership of the notices too.

Comment: I'd like to note that [the timeline appears to show the information (at least mostly) correctly.](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/33340211/timeline) The added/removed notices are attributed to the user.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has been fixed and will be out in the next deployment.