# What will happen with the bounty from a suspended user?

Tags: support, bounty, account-suspension

Just seeing this notification that:

> This question
>   has an open bounty worth +50 reputation from agon024 ending in 32
>   minutes.
>
> This question has not received enough attention.

[image]

Can someone explain me what is going on? The bounty is ending in 32 minutes and user's account is temporarily suspended, so how this user gonna see the answer? And this user has only 1 reputation, how this user gonna give 50 from his??

1 - 50 = -49.

[image]

Comment: He already gave it before being suspended?

Comment: but now he's suspended and can not use his account how he gonna see if he has got the right answer?

Comment: He won't. Because he is suspended.

Comment: Doesn't a users reputation get set to 1 while they are suspended and reset back when the suspension is lifted?

Comment: @Joe W: Yes, but the bounty has already been set which means the payout would have been deducted from their account prior to the suspension.

Comment: @BoltClock I understand that but it seems that not everyone knows about this change during a suspension.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The bounty was started before the user was suspended.

At that point they had enough reputation to be able to set a 50 point bounty.

While they won't be able to award the bounty manually, it will still get automatically awarded if there is a qualifying answer. (2+ upvotes scored after the bounty was started).

The user can still log into the site and see if there are any answers, but they can't vote or comment on them or accept an answer while suspended.

Comment: ok but user can accept the answer?

Comment: @MrJSingh - he can't, but the awarding of a bounty is independent of there being an accepted answer.

Comment: ok thanks, i think if user can not accept the answer then there shouldn't be bounty. it should be removed, it was confusing :-(

Comment: @MrJSingh The awarding of a bounty has nothing to do with whether the answer is accepted or not. In fact you might start a bounty to reward another answer on a question where you already accepted an answer - because it helped you and you can't accept two answers.

Comment: @MrJSingh Sometimes the [user is deleted before the bounty ends](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/320867/6083675) and the bounty must go on. I like to think of it as half the bounty being still valid.

Comment: Problem with this is that a bounty to reward an existing answer won't get awarded, since it does not qualify to get the bounty automatically.

Comment: @fedorqui, so? We really can't cater for every case and if someone starts a bounty and then does something suspension worthy they've really only got themselves to blame.

Comment: @ChrisF of course, agreed. But maybe in such cases the bounty should just be removed since it becomes useless.

Comment: @fedorqui, really? User sets a bounty then does something suspension worthy. I'd say that losing the bounty rep is the least of their worries. As to the potential recipients - those who provided existing answers should have no expectation of earning the bounty anyway.

Comment: Also the bounty's not useless. Half of it could be awarded to a new answer.

Comment: I agree on this being the least of their worries. My [little] point is that opening a bounty to reward an existing answer normally implies awarding it to an existing answer :)

Comment: @fedorqui - ah. OK - missed that, but again, it's really not something I'd be bothered about.

Comment: IIRC, the topic of bounties from suspended users was discussed quite recently - the foremost concern that was raised was that users who had no involvement with the suspended user would be penalised through no fault of their own. (In fact, I believe this was raised by a user who *was* suspended while having an open bounty.)